# Is it possible to create a new index on a Materialized View of the form 'create materialized view as'?

Tags: postgresql

```
(show server_version; 11.5)
```

I have a Materialized View:

```
drop materialized view if exists reporting.ecom_channel;
create materialized view reporting.ecom_channel  as


select 
    s.date,
    s.user_type,
    s.channel_grouping,
    s.device_category,
    sum(s.sessions) as sessions,
    count(distinct s.dimension2) as daily_users,
    sum(s.transactions) as transactions,
    sum(s.transaction_revenue) as revenue
from ecom.sessions s
group by 1,2,3,4
```

There is no id field on that query. For my regular tables, those are specified 'traditionally' with `'create table tablename .... id serial, field1 int, etc'`

Since I created my materialized view as being based on the results of a query as opposed to defining each field name during creation, how can I add a id?

The reason that I'm doing this is because when I tried:

```
refresh materialized view concurrently reporting.ecom_channel;
```

I got this error:

> ERROR: Cannot refresh materialized view "reporting.channel" concurrently. Hint: Create a unique index with no WHERE clause on one or more columns of the materialized view

How can I add an ID within the context of the above? With

```
create materialized view reporting.ecom_channel  as
select 
    s.date,
    s.user_type,
    ...
```

Comment: Title is asking for "index" but the question body clearly asks for adding an ID, i.e. an **id**entifier column. OP: "ID" stands for identifier or identity, not for index.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That unique index could be

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON reporting.ecom_channel (
   date,
   user_type,
   channel_grouping,
   device_category
);
```

This combination must be unique based on the query that defines the view.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. I wonder, is it not possible to create a new serial index as opposed to on all columns? Does it matter if the index has more columns?

Comment: Multi-column indexes are just fine. Adding an artificial counter wouldn't do what you want. The purpose of this index is that a row can be uniquely identified.

Comment: It would be possible to create a fake ID number in the view results by using a window function, such as `SELECT row_number() OVER () id, * FROM (SELECT ... ORDER BY ...) a`.  While this technique works great for a **one-time** generation of ID numbers to initialize a table from a query, it is **not** an appropriate solution for a materialized view like this.  The results would be completely renumbered every time the query runs, defeating the purpose of trying to uniquely identify the row.  As @LaurenzAlbe said, the multi-column index is the right solution here, not an artificial counter.